# How do you programmatically publish to the Facebook feed associated with a 'liked' page?

Tags: facebook

When you 'like' a page of a web site and you have the right meta tags, Facebook will essentially create a FB Page for that liked page. This gives you a way to update all fans of that page. To do it, you have to be listed as the admin of that page. It's all explained rather well here:

http://blog.roost.com/2010/07/23/like-button-enhancements-publish-fans/

Now, the question: suppose I don't want to have to go through the admin page link that I find next to all my like buttons? how can I publish directly to the graph object e.g. graph.facebook.com//feed ?

If I attempt to do this I need an access token. How do I get an access token to these generated FB pages?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is not as hard as I was making it. All you really need to do is create a facebook app, get an access token for that app and then publish to the /feed of the Liked page. Facebook's own doc explains it pretty well (for a change) here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

The only trick I discovered in figuring this out was that the FB app you specify with the meta tag MUST be hosted on the same domain as the pages being Liked.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm following instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/ and I've got my access token, but when I try to publish I get (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action